# UWP Xbox dev mode caches deployed app

Tags: uwp, xbox

I'm developing an Xbox app with a team of several developers and we have all experienced this scenario every day or so, where changes made to code aren't being deployed to the remote machine during debugging.

I'll make some code changes, then launch the app via Visual Studio to the "Remote Machine." The app launches, but I don't see the changes. If I inspect the XAML visual tree, areas of the app are highlighted on screen, but the tree reflects old XAML that I have since changed in the source.

When this happens, we go through various combinations of the following: restarting the console, manually uninstalling the app via the Xbox, leaving dev mode and launching it again. We've yet to stumble on the magic combo, but eventually after doing one or more of the above (usually more than once), the issue is resolved.

We're wasting a lot of our dev time dealing with this issue. Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid it or at least a faster way to reset things than restarting the console?

Comment: XBONE or 360? If you're under NDA with MS, your rep should be able to help resolve this quite quickly. Also, gamedev.stackexchange.com would be a better place to post this.

Comment: ONE, UWP...updated title to reflect that.

Comment: I missed the UWP part.

Comment: I've seen this with other .NET apps, but not on the Xbox. Are you rebuilding the app before deploying / starting the debugger? (Have to ask.)

Comment: Yup, rebuild, clean solution, etc., doesn't help.

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue with latest SDK? The Creator update allow you to do Live Debugging also and I never experiences something like this. Unless your code isn't compiled and you only need to uninstall your app on xbox and deploy again.